# Best way to make a Ghillie suit in Blender?

Tags: modeling, objects

So I have a basic T pose female character that I'm using for a sniper game I am creating with a friend. I'd love to have a ghillie suit on her, as It's going to be very stealthy game, and we'd like to make use of the camouflage.

The problem I'm having is actually creating the grass and/or leaves/branches. I'm not entirely sure the best way to tackle it, and being very new to blender, I was hoping someone with a bit more experience could point me in the right direction and give me a few tips. As I'm stuck for what to do, your help would be extremely invaluable.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: Thanks for the replies, brasshat. The engine will be/is Unreal Engine 4 (version 4.8.3 specifically) and we intend to just have a static ghillie suit for now, so we can get the basic look going to aid us in camouflage, etc. The eventual plan could probably be give it a few basic physics like swaying and such. But that is months down the line. I'm aware of the online courses, but any chance you could share a few ways that'd be suitable for this? that way I can focus on what I need to learn specifically

Comment: Particle system?

Comment: Wow, I looked up the 'particle system' as you suggested and that's looking very promising so far. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Blender, Chris. Learning to use a platform like Blender always involves pushing the envelope of one's skill set, but in my experience it's common for people in some platforms and applications of those platforms, to push parts of the envelope too much. A question which includes some analogue of "what's the best way" in one of the things that tell me that the questioner is probably pushing the envelope too much. I suggest that you look at [question 15355](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender/), and take one of the on-line courses under "learning".

Comment: I was not previously familiar with a "Ghillie suit" so I looked it up on on Wikipedia. Off the top of my head, I can think of several ways to use Blender to represent them, but the exact way will depend upon knowing exactly how you intend for the suit to function in game, and what game engine is to be used. For me, there is not enough information to answer what the best way is. As written, I consider the question too broad, but I am not voting to close it.

Comment: That reminds me, I tried the particle system and it seemed like a great Idea, but the more I looked into it the more I heard that It is terrible for use in a game. So I scrapped that Idea.